# JQuery: Referencing outer scope within callback

Tags: javascript, jquery, callback

I have an issue with OO Javascript and a jQuery callback.
If you look at the sample below it should explain everything.

How do I call functionToCall() deep within this functception.

```
function outerClass() {
    this.functionToCall = function() {
        //do something
    }

    this.someOtherFunction = function() {

    this.aCoupleOfVariables1 = 2;
    this.aCoupleOfVariables2 = "stuff";

    $.ajax({
        success: function() {
        //How do I call functionToCall() right here
        //TRIED:
            functionToCall();
            this.functionToCall();
            that.functionToCall();
        }
    }); 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can pass `this` as the `context` option to [$.ajax()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/):

```
$.ajax({
    context: this,
    success: function() {
        // Here, 'this' refers to the same object as in the caller.
        this.functionToCall();  
    }
});
```

Comment: Ooo, I like this so much more.

Comment: Just a sidenote for the OP: whenever you need to make use of `this` and can't use `context` or any other property for the matter (lots of cases), http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.proxy/

Comment: Nice, this avoids having to use $.proxy as well.

Answer (score 6):

Have a local reference to it,

```
function outerClass() {

    var self = this;

    this.functionToCall = function() {
    //do something
    }

    this.someOtherFunction = function() {

    this.aCoupleOfVariables1 = 2;
    this.aCoupleOfVariables2 = "stuff";

    $.ajax({
        success: function() {
           self.functionToCall();
       }
    }); 
   }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

You need to define `that` in the outer scope.

```
function outerClass() {
    var that = this;

    // ...

     $.ajax({
        success: function() {
            that.functionToCall();
        }
    }); 
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You need to store the reference for the `this value` from the parent scope:

```
var parentScope = this;
```

and then access `functionToCall` via that object

```
parentScope.functionToCall();
```

Example:

```
function outerClass() {
    var parentScope = this;

    this.functionToCall = function() {
        //do something
    }

    // ...

    $.ajax({
       success: function() {
           parentScope.functionToCall();
       }
    });
}
```

---

Another way to accomplish that would be to use Es5's `.bind()` to set the value for `this` within your inner function(-context)

```
$.ajax({
    success: function() {
        // Here, 'this' refers to the same object as in the caller.
        this.functionToCall();  
    }.bind(this)
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Maintain the scope of the function in a local variable and use it or you can also use jquery `proxy` in which you can specify the context.

```
function outerClass() {
    this.functionToCall = function() {
        //do something
    }

    this.someOtherFunction = function() {

    this.aCoupleOfVariables1 = 2;
    this.aCoupleOfVariables2 = "stuff";


    $.ajax({
        success: $.proxy(function() {
            this.functionToCall();
        }, this)
    }); 
    }
}
```