# How to take functions inside - jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, scope

I am using jQuery **[Block UI plugin](http://www.malsup.com/jquery/block/)**. like below;

```
$('#someid .someclass').click(function(){
  var id = "someidx";
  var newval = "somevalx";
  $.blockUI({
    onBlock: function() {
      $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'target.php',
        data: 'data='+newval,
        cache: false,
        success: function(result) {
          if(result == "true"){
            $('#mymessage').addClass("asuccess");
          }else{
            $('#mymessage').addClass("aerror");
          }
        }
      });
     },
     onUnblock: function(){
       //some functions;
     },
     message: $('#mymessage'),  
  });
  $(this).hide();
  $(this).siblings('.class1').hide();
  $(this).siblings('.class2').show();
  $(this).parent("td").siblings(".class3").html(newval);
});
```

This works fine. But I want to do some functions inside `if(result == "true")`. That is, I want to do those things if ajax result is true. I want to do;

```
success: function(result) {
  if(result == "true"){
    $('#mymessage').addClass("asuccess");
    $(this).hide();
    $(this).siblings('.class1').hide();
    $(this).siblings('.class2').show();
    $(this).parent("td").siblings(".class3").html(newval);
  }else{
    $('#mymessage').addClass("aerror");
  }
}
```

if ajax return is true, and take these things into success nesting. But this is not working inside `if(result == "true")` nesting. How can I achieve this?

Comment: Try doing a `console.log(result)` to see what it actually contains.

Comment: What do you mean by "not working"?  What is `console.log(result)`?  Inside your `success` function, `this` is not what you think it is.

Comment: The functions are not executing when taking inside ajax success nesting. otherwise its okay.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can set a variable in your top function as `this` and use that in the inner one.

```
$('#someid .someclass').click(function () {

    var self = $(this);

    var id = "someidx";
    var newval = "somevalx";
    $.blockUI({
        onBlock: function () {
            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: 'target.php',
                data: 'data=' + newval,
                cache: false,
                success: function (result) {
                    if (result == "true") {
                        $('#mymessage').addClass("asuccess");
                        self.hide();
                        self.siblings('.cancel').hide();
                        self.siblings('.edit').show();
                        self.parent("td").siblings(".cell2").html(newval);
                    } else {
                        $('#mymessage').addClass("aerror");
                    }
                }
            });
        },
        onUnblock: function () {
            //some functions;
        },
        message: $('#mymessage'),

    });
});
```

Comment: Which is effectively the same as adding the "context" property to the options :-)

Comment: Pretty much, didn't know about `context` before this. Handy :P

Comment: Not in this case. Note the nesting, Daniel's solution is correct, using context with `this` is not.

Comment: can improve by caching `var $self=$(this)` insetad of making extra jQuery calls

Comment: @DanielImms crap sorry for the edit - I thought it was the OP :-)

Comment: @Pointy nps, it's more handsome now.

Answer (score 3):

Add

```
    context: self,  // oops - fixed now (was "this")
```

to your `$.ajax()` call.  That'll make sure that `this` refers to the clicked element when the AJAX callbacks are invoked. Without that, `this` refers to the ajax settings object, not the original DOM element.

*edit* — also you'd need the "self" var as in the answer from Daniel Imms (which itself will suit perfectly without this "context" thing).

Comment: The `$(this).hide()` code simply won't work unless `this` refers to the clicked element. So, given that, why the downvote?

Comment: He's not even referencing `this` in his ajax handlers.

Comment: @jmar777 please re-read his question. He wants to move those four lines of code (all starting with `$(this)`) into the "success" handler.

Comment: [Yes this is right](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6998140/jquery-referencing-outer-scope-within-callback)...+1

Comment: @jmar777 no worries, it happens to me hourly :-)

Comment: -1: I don't agree with that solution. `this` refers to `$.blockUI` (note the nesting).

Comment: @freakish ah OK you may be right; I was going to edit in some proper spacing but I got lazy :-)  I'll update the answer.

Comment: @freakish yea I realized that :-) I grabbed Mr. Imms's answer erroneously!  His is fine, and you're right in this case "context" is pointless unless you really love using `this`.  I've been trying to train myself to remember the feature however and I guess that leaked out here.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#someid .someclass').click(function(){
    var self = $(this);
    // other code
});
```

You can now use `self` in your AJAX handler as a reference to clicked element.